# Php open CMD window form php script

Tags: php, cmd, windows-10

I'm working on windows 10 machine with apache 2.4 and php 7.0.1.

I'm trying to open cmd or any application window form php script and each time window is open in background instead visible. I was try:

```
shell_exec( 'cmd');    

shell_exec( 'START "" /MAX CMD');

exec('cmd.exe');

exec('echo . | cmd.exe /C start "" /MAX "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe');

$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd", 3, false);
```

I was try each possible combintaion and doesn't really help me. The same situation is when i replace cmd with any other application like notepad par example.

Can any one give me a helpen hand and give me tips, what to do to open windows program not in background?

Comment: If this is running inside `apache`, the `cmd` instance is started inside the same session of the `apache` executable, not your desktop session. You can test running `apache` as a desktop application and not as a service.

Comment: Shortest answer is. IMPOSSIBLE

Comment: Re-read comment by @MCND `the cmd instance is started inside the same session of the apache executable, not your desktop session`

Comment: And how to start apache as desktop application? httpd.exe -k starts or stops service...

Comment: Directly use `httpd.exe`